# Import pandas syntax error?

Tags: python, pandas

I've imported pandas before and haven't made any changes to the pandas code, but now I start to see this error. I have no idea what to do since I didn't change anything involving pandas. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 361, in <module>
    from dateutil import parser as _date_parser
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 158
    l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, `value`))
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: that use of backticks was removed in python3 (use python2 or a newer pandas version)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ currently using 0.20.3, the weird part is I was using this last week and it was working fine...

Comment: @jonatan I upgraded pandas and it fixed my issue, thank you!!